# nopcommerce-How to get customer and verdor geolocations?

Tags: nopcommerce

I want to track customer location and vendor locations. E.g: I am customer and i need service from vendors which are in 10km range of my location. For this functionality i need to track customer location and vendor location and then find all venders which are in 10km range.

Does nopcommerce is having any plugins for this functionality or we need to customize current functionality. If we need to customize then please help me how to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're at wrong place if you're asking for third party plugin, that is off topic here. If you're asking for customization, here to go:

1). Integrate Google map with registration page, user have to select location by search or draggable marker.

2). Save lat/long to the DB (add custom field or use plugin table).

3). Query by current user location and get all lat/long(range of 10km) from database and show it to the map.

*Bonus: you can refer nopCommerce pickup point code, they have used Geo-Location service over there*

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for customization approach... I found one plugin store locator https://www.nop-templates.com/store-locator-plugin-for-nopcommerce-documentation